# Python: How can i input lines read from a text file into a variable

Tags: python, forms, fill, auto

I'm currently working on a python script to develop a automatic fill form bot. Only doing 1 site until i get the process down. As of the moment i have 2 options. Option 1 is to input the client data manually, the script then takes this data into a variable to use for send.keys in order to fill the form on the particular website. This is working fine. Now my problem is with Option 2. I'm trying to import lines read from a text file. Store that data as content. The attach each lines (content[0]) to a variable, then use that variable with the send.keys command to auto fill the form. For example, My text file contains this data:

John Doe
123 Test Street
Test City

I want to be able to read each line individually and assign it content.
Line 1 would be read as content0
Line 2 would be read as content1
Line 3 would be read as content2
So on and so forth.

Then i would assign this value to a variable. Example.

```
FirstName = (content[0])
Address = (content[1])
City = (content[2])
```

Then my goal is to take this and use it with the send.keys command, so my bot fills in the box with the corresponding data.

This is where i am stuck at. When the script open the web page and starts the auto fill nothing displays in the boxes. if i add str like this str content[0] then it fills in the box with "content[0]" instead of the variable i have content assigned too. My code below.

```
if inputchoice == '2':  

    file = open('info.txt', 'r')
    read_=file.read()

    Phoneinput = (content[0])
    FirstNameinput = (content[1])
    LastNameinput = (content[2])
    Addyinput = (content[3])
    Cityinput = (content[4])
    Stateinput = (content[5])
    Stateinput2 = (content[6])
    Zipinput = (content[7])
    Emailinput1 = (content[8])

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://www.listyourself.net/ListYourself/listing.jsp')
time.sleep(2)

Phone1 = web.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]')
Phone1.send_keys(str(Phoneinput))
```

Comment: `Phoneinput = (content[0])` You haven't shown us what `content` is...

Comment: If you want to access the lines in a file, use `.readlines()` instead of `.read()`.

Comment: The content is the data from the text file. content[0] would be the first line in the text file automatically. This is what i was told am i wrong?

Comment: Your code is `read_=file.read()`.  So the file content is in the variable `read_`, not the variable `content`.  I am confused.

Comment: you are correct i changed that did a test run i did see it input the correct info in the fill form. After the first line my program closes. Looking into thanks

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
read_=file.read()
```

reads the *entire* contents of the file into a single `str` value assigned to the variable `read`. You then try to access the non-existent variable `contents` with the assumption that `contents` is a *list* whose elements are the individual lines. Replace the call to `file.read` with

```
contents = file.readlines()
```

to make your assumption true.

Comment: Does readlines() read each individual line? I can get the first line to read with (content[0]) cant seem to read the rest

Comment: @val416 Yes it returns a list of each separate line.  Does your file actually have more than one line?

Comment: yes it does about 10 lines of code i need to input @johngordon each having there own send key

Comment: What does `print(contents)` show you? If your file has more than one line, it should show you a list containing each line. "can't seem to read the rest" isn't much to go on.

Comment: If you use `.read()` then `content[0]` will not be the first _line_ in the file, it will be the first _single character_ in the file.  If you want lines, use `.readlines()`.

Comment: I did change it to readlines() and print(content) prints all the data im trying to input. so that's working for sure. Seems to be fine. I will make a new post explaining my new problem as its diverting from the original content of this post. Thank you guys!